# Remove X char from string

Tags: php

I need to know how to do this reliably with the least amount of calls.

I have a string and I need to remove the 8th character from it. It doesn't matter what the char is, I just need to remove ONLY the 8th char.

I came up with this but a little too unwieldy for me.

```
//      12345678901234567890
$str = '5NMSG3AB1AH353158';
// after removing char, result should be:
// 5NMSG3A1AH353158
$r = str_split($str);
unset($r[7]);
echo join('', $r);
```

Possibly Regex?

Comment: `preg_replace('/(.{7}).(.*)/', '$1$2', $str)`. Note, if you use multibyte encoding, you have to add `u` modifier

Comment: @rgen3 - almost the same as my Idea ... :).  You don't have to capture the remaining part of the string if you use the `^` start of string anchor.

Comment: yes, they are quite the same, your solution may be a little faster than mine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`substr_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) makes this very simple.

```
$string = substr_replace($string, '', 7, 1);
```

It can also take an array of strings as its first parameter, and do the same replacement in all of them, which can be pretty handy.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some solutions:

```
$str = substr($str, 0, 7) . substr($str, 8);
$str = substr_replace($str, '', 7, 1);
$str = preg_replace('/(.{7})./', '$1', $str, 1);
$str = preg_replace('/.{7}\K./', '', $str, 1);
```

I'd go for `substr()` or better `substr_replace()` as this will certainly be fastest and most easy to read.

Comment: You forgot `echo str_split($str, 7)[0].str_split($str, 8)[1];`

Comment: And this one `echo substr_replace($s,'',7,1);`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yes, `substr_replace()`! The `str_split()` one doesn't work as is on shorter or longer strings, so we'd need another calls like `strlen()` or `substr()`. Thanks! +1

Comment: need both `echo str_split($str, 7)[0].substr($str, 8, strlen($str));` actually.  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/001467b0bf7b0577a286e9ab888dc1632d497fdd)  But that sort of ruins the charm.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
$str = '5NMSG3AB1AH353158';
echo preg_replace('/^(.{7})./', '\1', $str);
```

Output:

```
5NMSG3A1AH353158
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6369a4758ad63c7afabfc01664785aabc91d2f2a)

Explanation

- `^` start of string
- `(...)` capture
- `.` match any
- `{7}` seven times
- `.` match any one time

Then the replacement

- `\1`  first capture group

Basically capture the first 7 chars, then match the 8th, and replace that with the captured 7 chars.  Which effectively removes the 8th.

**UPDATE**

here is another way I like (I haven't used that function sense college, I think):

```
$s = '5NMSG3A1AH353158';
echo substr_replace($s,'',7,1); //strings are 0 based
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5844bbe331ec6d2136bc0b91bb80bf41bf8edcdc)

> **substr_replace()** replaces a copy of string delimited by the start and (optionally) length parameters with the string given in replacement.
>
> mixed **substr_replace**( mixed **$string**, mixed **$replacement**, mixed **$start** [, mixed **$length** ] )

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

Simple.